# jQuery get value after change of price slider

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to retrieve value from price slider after change.

Price slider:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
 $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 5000,
  values: [ 500, 2000 ],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " kr" + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] + " kr" );
  },
change: function(event, ui) {
    filterBy(ui);
}
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " kr" +
  " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + " kr" );
});
</script>
```

filterBy(ui)

```
  <script>
    function filterBy(ui) { 
   $('.searchtable').addClass('hide');
   $('.spinner').removeClass('hide');

   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'name':'<?php echo strval($_GET['name']); ?>','arrival':'<?php echo strval($_GET['arrival']); ?>','departure':'<?php echo strval($_GET['departure']);?>','guests':'<?php echo strval($_GET['guests']);?>','minRate':$("#amount").val(ui.values[0]),'propertyCategory':$("#hotelType input[type='checkbox']:checked").val(),'minStarRating':$("#hotelRating input[type='checkbox']:checked").val()},
        url: '<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/hotels/hotelFilterResult.php',


        success: function (data) {
            alert('data loaded succesfully');
            alert(this.url);

            $('.searchtable').replaceWith(data);
            $('.spinner').addClass('hide');
            $('.searchtable').removeClass('hide');

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('data not loaded');
        }
  });

 }
 </script>
```

Trying to get current value of the price slider in first position (0). Into this data element:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'name':'<?php echo strval($_GET['name']); ?>','arrival':'<?php echo strval($_GET['arrival']); ?>','departure':'<?php echo strval($_GET['departure']);?>','guests':'<?php echo strval($_GET['guests']);?>','minRate':$("#amount").val(ui.values[0]),'propertyCategory':$("#hotelType input[type='checkbox']:checked").val(),'minStarRating':$("#hotelRating input[type='checkbox']:checked").val(),'amenities':$("#hotelAmenities input[type='checkbox']:checked").val()},
        url: '<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/hotels/hotelFilterResult.php',
```

Trying to retrieve it by this :

```
'minRate':$("#amount").val(ui.values[0])
```

But it doesen't work - how do I get the current value from the price slider in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:
$("#amount").slider( "value" )
instead of 
$("#amount").val(ui.values[0])

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin

make sure you display the source code on the jquery site.

Or, if you try to call this in your filterBy() function, make sure you pass ui as a parameter?

Just a guess...

Comment: yes I try to call inside filterBy() - how do I pass the ui parameter?

Comment: Ah I see you use a range slider so calling ("values") is fine. As for filterBy I would try: in your change event handler: filterBy(ui) and don't forget the parameter in your function definition function filterBy(ui)

Comment: so having it say filterBy(ui) should pass the parameters ? @vm2013

Comment: It should, I would however try to access the value by 'minRate':ui.values[0]

Comment: yeah ui.values is an array, in your case [0] is the min value, [1] is the max value. I think on jquery, $("#<any id").val(something) actually tries to set the value of an object, whereas to read it, it should be $("#<any id").val(). But that doesn't work on plugins like the slider, from my experience. It works on HTML tags such as <input> or <select>.